# Upload a file created using FileSystem API to S3 bucket using JavaScript

Tags: javascript, amazon-web-services, file-upload, amazon-s3, html5-filesystem

When I am trying to upload a file (FILE_PATH) to S3 bucket it's getting uploaded but I am getting file path (FILE_PATH) as content in the file. Please can you tell where I am doing it wrong?

I followed this link https://www.html5rocks.com/en/tutorials/file/filesystem/#toc-file to create a file and write into it.

Everything seems to work except that I am getting file path (FILE_PATH) as content in the uploaded file

Here is my code.

```
var FILE_PATH = 'filesystem:http://localhost:5000/temporary'

  function onInitFs(fs) {
    fs.root.getFile('log.json', {create: true}, function(fileEntry) {

      fileEntry.createWriter(function(fileWriter) {

        fileWriter.onwriteend = function(e) {
          console.log('Write completed.');
        };

        fileWriter.onerror = function(e) {
          console.log('Write failed: ' + e.toString());
        };

        var sukshi_dict = {
          "sfds": "sdfse"
        }

        var sukshi_dict = JSON.stringify(sukshi_dict);
        var blob = new Blob([sukshi_dict], {type: "application/json"});
        fileWriter.write(blob);
        addPhoto('hero', FILE_PATH)
      }, errorHandler);
      FILE_PATH = FILE_PATH + fileEntry.fullPath
      console.log(FILE_PATH)
    }, errorHandler);

  }

  window.requestFileSystem(window.TEMPORARY, 5*1024*1024 /*5MB*/, onInitFs, errorHandler);

function addPhoto(albumName, file_path) {
    debugger
    var file = file_path;
    if (!file.length) {
      return alert('Please choose a file to upload first.');
    }
    var fileName = file.substring(file.lastIndexOf('/')+1);
    console.log(fileName)
    var albumPhotosKey = encodeURIComponent(albumName) + '/';

    var photoKey = albumPhotosKey + fileName;
    s3.upload({
      Key: photoKey,
      Body: file,
      ACL: 'public-read'
    }, function(err, data) {
      if (err) {
        return alert('There was an error uploading your photo: ', err.message);
      }
      alert('Successfully uploaded photo.');
    });
  }
```